# Windows 2008R2 VM will not boot, won't boot from cdrom cdrom, Bootmgr is missing ESX 4.0

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Since I can't boot to the cdrom, I can't get to the repair options suggested in other posts.
Suggestions? TIA

Comment: I was able to get to the bios after several tries, gotta be fast, so I can at least now boot a cdrom

Comment: Next time just go into the settings of the VM>Options>Boot Options and set the `Power On Boot Delay` to something like 5000 (5 seconds) or whatever you like.